# How to align nodes and edges in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am going through an O'Reilly data science book and it gives you the python code to more or less create this node viz ...

[image]

But it doesn't tell you how to make the viz as its not really relevant to the subject but I wanted to take a crack at it anyway and so far this is as close as I've come

```
users = [
{ "id": 0, "name": "Hero" },
{ "id": 1, "name": "Dunn" },
{ "id": 2, "name": "Sue" },
{ "id": 3, "name": "Chi" },
{ "id": 4, "name": "Thor" },
{ "id": 5, "name": "Clive" },
{ "id": 6, "name": "Hicks" },
{ "id": 7, "name": "Devin" },
{ "id": 8, "name": "Kate" },
{ "id": 9, "name": "Klein" },
{ "id": 10, "name": "Jen" }
]

friendships = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4),
           (4, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 9)]

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([user["id"] for user in users])
G.add_edges_from(friendships)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, node_size=1000)
```

[image]

This is brand new to me both python and networkx - I can't seem to figure out from their documentation what actual graph I should be using - I tried just about every one of them and none get me there - is it possible in networkx to align nodes this way and what is the correct graph to use?

Is networkx the right tool for this job is there a better python lib for this task?

**UPDATE**

@Aric answer was perfect but I made a couple changes to make the nodes match the data rather than the static type array. I don't think this is the 'best' way to do the calculation someone with more python experience would know better. I played with the minimum sizes and positions for a bit and STILL I could not get it pixel perfect but still I'm pretty happy with the end result

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([user["id"] for user in users])
G.add_edges_from(friendships)
pos = {0: [0,0],
       1: [4,-0.35],
       2: [4,0.35],
       3: [8,0],
       4: [12,0],
       5: [16,0],
       6: [20,0.35],
       7: [20,-0.35],
       8: [24,0],
       9: [28,0],
       10: [32,0]}

nodes = [user["id"] for user in users]
def calcSize(node):
    minSize = 450
    friends = number_of_friends(node)
    if friends <= 0:
        return minSize
    return minSize * friends

node_size = [(calcSize(user)) for user in users]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_size=node_size, node_color='#c4daef')
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.axis('off')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar with NetworkX.  You'll need use a different layout method than "spring_layout" or set the node positions explicitly like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([user["id"] for user in users])
G.add_edges_from(friendships)
pos = {0: [0,0],
       1: [1,-0.25],
       2: [1,0.25],
       3: [2,0],
       4: [3,0],
       5: [4,0],
       6: [5,0.25],
       7: [5,-0.25],
       8: [6,0],
       9: [7,0],
       10: [8,0]}

nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
node_size = [500, 1000, 1000, 1000,  500, 1000, 500, 500 , 1000, 300, 300]
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, nodelist=nodes, node_size=node_size, node_color='#c4daef')
plt.ylim(-1,1)
plt.axis('off')
```

[image]